# SPServices to retrieve the last record of repeated section data inside Sharepoint library

Tags: infopath, javascript, spservices, field-controls

I have a Infopath that contain 2 fields which I put it as a repeating section as shown in the picture below (for the time being - please ignore the error)

[image]

How do I retrieve the last record of a repeating field using SPServices or any Javascript code? (In the picture above, the last record will be - Telephone Test 14)